# Invalid column name using row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY )

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, inner-join

I have two tables `TBL_CONTACT` and `TBL_PHONE` that I am trying to join.

The `TBL_PHONE` table contains duplicate rows for contacts with multiple phone numbers, so I am partitioning these and trying to select the first instance only.

Here is the code I have:

```
SELECT
    (CONTACT.CONTACTID),
    (CONTACT.FULLNAME),
    (PHONE.contactid),
    (PHONE.numberdisplay),
    (row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY PHONE.Contactid ORDER BY PHONE.Contactid)) prn
FROM
    "ACT2015Demo"."dbo"."TBL_CONTACT" AS CONTACT
INNER JOIN
    TBL_PHONE AS PHONE
    ON CONTACT.Contactid = PHONE.Contactid
WHERE
    CAST(Editdate AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

This gives the following:

```
CONTACTID   FULLNAME   CONTACTID    NUMBERDISPLAY   PRN
1001        Name1      1001         Tel1001 1       1
1001        Name1      1001         Tel1001 2       2
1002        Name2      1002         Tel1002 1       1
1003        Name3      1003         Tel1003 1       1
1003        Name3      1003         Tel1003 2       2
1003        Name3      1003         Tel1003 3       3
```

I then want to use the PRN column to limit the output to only rows with PRN = 1. I have tried the following, as this has worked for me in the past on less complex joins:

```
SELECT
    (CONTACT.CONTACTID),
    (CONTACT.FULLNAME),
    (PHONE.contactid),
    (PHONE.numberdisplay),
    (row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY PHONE.Contactid ORDER BY PHONE.Contactid)) prn
FROM
    "ACT2015Demo"."dbo"."TBL_CONTACT" AS CONTACT
INNER JOIN
    TBL_PHONE AS PHONE
    ON CONTACT.Contactid = PHONE.Contactid AND PRN = 1
WHERE
    CAST(Editdate AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

However, this gives me the invalid column name error for `PRN`? I have also tried using `PRN = 1` as part of the `WHERE` with the same error.

How can I get `PRN` to work as a column name and limit the output?

Comment: Wrap your query with another that only picks PRN=1

Comment: You can't perform "secondary" functions (filtering, ordering, etc) based on window functions.

Comment: Wait, MySQL has windowing functions now!?

Comment: What database are you using?  You tagged MySQL, but it doesn't look like it is.

Comment: changed tag based on syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the following, as this has worked for me in the past on less complex joins...The way you tried will never work for simple joins as well.You have to use Derived table or CTE

```
Select 
*
from
(
SELECT
    (CONTACT.CONTACTID) as concontactid,
    (CONTACT.FULLNAME),
    (PHONE.contactid),
    (PHONE.numberdisplay),
    (row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY PHONE.Contactid ORDER BY PHONE.Contactid)) prn
FROM
    "ACT2015Demo"."dbo"."TBL_CONTACT" AS CONTACT
INNER JOIN
    TBL_PHONE AS PHONE
    ON CONTACT.Contactid = PHONE.Contactid 
WHERE
    CAST(Editdate AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
) as b
where prn=1
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried your derived table suggestion and CTE, but both give:  The column 'contactid' was specified multiple times for 'b'

Comment: You have contact.contactid and phone.contactid in the select statement.

Comment: @sstan:mysql don't support window functions,it seems op wrongly tagged it

Answer (score 3):

Something a bit weird and confusing for some people about SQL is that column aliases you define in the select-list cannot be referenced in the `FROM` clause or `WHERE` clause.

This is confusing because of the fact that column aliases appear to be defined early in the query (as the select-list is before the `FROM` clause). But the order of the syntax is not the order of execution.

You can get around this by running your query as a *derived table* subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT
        CONTACT.CONTACTID,
        CONTACT.FULLNAME,
        PHONE.contactid,
        PHONE.numberdisplay,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PHONE.Contactid ORDER BY PHONE.Contactid) AS PRN
    FROM
        "ACT2015Demo"."dbo"."TBL_CONTACT" AS CONTACT
    INNER JOIN
        TBL_PHONE AS PHONE
        ON CONTACT.Contactid = PHONE.Contactid
    WHERE
        CAST(Editdate AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
    ) AS DerivedTable
WHERE PRN = 1
```

PS: MySQL does not support windowing functions in versions up to 5.7. It has been announced that this feature is being worked on, hopefully it will be ready in MySQL 8. I think you may have tagged your question incorrectly.

You use the schema qualifier `dbo` which makes me think you are using Microsoft SQL Server or Sybase, is this correct?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and yes I didn't mean to add the mysql tag.

Answer (score 2):

This error also happens when the *row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY )* clause has a **composite set of key fields** which appear in both tables in the join.  The error will not go away no-matter how the aliases are arranged or rearranged.  To solve this, the identically named key columns from the joining table must be renamed in an in-line temporary table as follows.
**Change this:**

```
    INNER JOIN
    TBL_PHONE AS PHONE
    ON CONTACT.Contactid = PHONE.Contactid 
    ... some other col_names 
    etc. ...
```

**to this:**

```
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            Contactid as PK_Contactid,
            ... some other col_names as PK_col_names,
            etc. ...
        FROM TBL_PHONE
        ) AS PHONE
    ON CONTACT.Contactid = PHONE.PK_Contactid
    ... some other col_names 
    etc. ...
```

**NB.** and **don't prefix the any *col_names* with table aliases** in the *row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY )* clause at all. Worked for me.